# Return 0 if field is null in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySQL, is there a way to set the "total" fields to zero if they are NULL?

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT uo.order_id, uo.order_total, uo.order_status,
            (SELECT SUM(uop.price * uop.qty) 
             FROM uc_order_products uop 
             WHERE uo.order_id = uop.order_id
            ) AS products_subtotal,
            (SELECT SUM(upr.amount) 
             FROM uc_payment_receipts upr 
             WHERE uo.order_id = upr.order_id
            ) AS payment_received,
            (SELECT SUM(uoli.amount) 
             FROM uc_order_line_items uoli 
             WHERE uo.order_id = uoli.order_id
            ) AS line_item_subtotal
            FROM uc_orders uo
            WHERE uo.order_status NOT IN ("future", "canceled")
            AND uo.uid = 4172;
```

The data comes out fine, except the NULL fields should be `0`.

How can I return 0 for NULL in MySQL?

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
IFNULL(expr1, 0)
```

From the documentation:

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Would that be IFNULL((SELECT SUM(uop.price * uop.qty) FROM uc_order_products uop WHERE uo.order_id = uop.order_id) AS products_subtotal, 0)?

Comment: @Kevin: No  - the alias goes at the end.

Comment: @MarkByers can you show why Kevin's example in the comment is wrong and what it should actually be?

Comment: thank you so much !! This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @MarkByers IFNOtNULL(expr1, 1)  is there anything like that

Comment: IFNULL(expr1,0,20) something like that if not null then set that value @MarkByers thank you

Answer (score 31):

You can use `coalesce(column_name,0)` instead of just `column_name`. The [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function returns the first non-NULL value in the list.

I should mention that per-row functions like this are usually problematic for scalability. If you think your database may get to be a decent size, it's often better to use extra columns and triggers to move the cost from the `select` to the `insert/update`.

This amortises the cost assuming your database is read more often than written (and most of them are).

Comment: This happens once a week to bill all customers. Data is written all week, then at a certain time, its computed and billed. Think of it like a subscription service. You can make changes during the tenure of the billing period, and your activity is charged at appropriate intervals.

Comment: I would add that in this situation that I would prefer coalesce becasue it's the same syntax for MS and My SQLs, whereas MS SQL is iSnull and MySQL is iFnull, if that matters to anyone.  (MySQLs ISNULL is a different function than MS SQL's ISNULL)

Answer (score 29):

None of the above answers were complete for me.
If your field is named `field`, so the selector should be the following one:

```
IFNULL(`field`,0) AS field
```

For example in a SELECT query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`field`,0) AS field, `otherfield` FROM `mytable`
```

Hope this can help someone to not waste time.

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(X, '' ), 0)
```

Attribute X is assumed to be empty if it is an empty String, so after that you can declare as a zero instead of last value. In another case, it would remain its original value.

Anyway, just to give another way to do that.

Comment: This worked for me great in the middle of a SELECT vs the normal IFNULL(var, 0)

Answer (score 5):

Yes IFNULL function will be working to achieve your desired result.

```
SELECT uo.order_id, uo.order_total, uo.order_status,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(uop.price * uop.qty),0) 
         FROM uc_order_products uop 
         WHERE uo.order_id = uop.order_id
        ) AS products_subtotal,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(upr.amount),0) 
         FROM uc_payment_receipts upr 
         WHERE uo.order_id = upr.order_id
        ) AS payment_received,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(uoli.amount),0) 
         FROM uc_order_line_items uoli 
         WHERE uo.order_id = uoli.order_id
        ) AS line_item_subtotal
        FROM uc_orders uo
        WHERE uo.order_status NOT IN ("future", "canceled")
        AND uo.uid = 4172;
```