# my count for calculated columns again is coming wrong with the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Working with the below query, my query is returning the results, but for two calculated columns: `solditems` and `leftoverstock` are still coming as EMPTY. I want to show 0 if it is empty rather than null and show value if they have some value

here is my code:

```
select items.itemID,items.itemcode,items.itemname,items.qty,items.unitcost,items.unitprice,items.categoryID,items.status,
 tbl_suppliers.suppliername,
units.unit,(select sum(ABS(quantity)) from orders 
where itemid=1) as itemsordered_notsold,items.weight,items.length,items.width,items.height,
items.addedon,items.notes,(select sum(ABS(quantity)) from sales 
where itemID=1) as solditems,(select SUM(ABS(itemsordered_notsold - `solditems`))) as 
leftoverstock 
from 
items inner join categories on items.categoryID = categories.catID 
inner join tbl_suppliers on tbl_suppliers.ID = items.supplierID 
inner join units on units.unitID = items.unitmeasureID
where itemID=1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return 0 if field is null in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997327/return-0-if-field-is-null-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a call to COALESCE as:

```
COALESCE((select sum(ABS(quantity)) 
          from sales where itemID=1), 0)
```

COALESCE return it's leftmost non-null value