# Mysql change null value to 0

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL statement for my mysql database.

```
SELECT MAX(customer_ID) AS high_customer_ID FROM `customers`.`customers` WHERE our_customer_ID=1;
```

but whene ther is no customer_ID with our_customer_ID = 1 then the statment return null but I want it to return 0 how do i do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return 0 if field is null in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997327/return-0-if-field-is-null-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to assign a default value in case of a `null`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(customer_ID), 0) AS high_customer_ID 
FROM   `customers`.`customers`
WHERE  our_customer_id = 1;
```