# How can I set 0 if a query return a null value in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT sum(intervento.IMP_IND_POS_AFF_MIN) 
FROM TID023_INTERVENTO intervento
INNER JOIN TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario 
   ON(enteBeneficiario.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst 
   ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = enteBeneficiario.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE intervento.COD_TIP_BAN=1 AND intervento.IMP_IND_POS_AFF_MIN is not null;
```

This query works fine but, as you can see, it doesn't retrieve a set of rows but return a number that is obtained by the **sum()** function.

This number in some case could be **null**, in this case I don't want that this query return **null** (because it creates problem in my application) but in this case have to be returned the numeric value **0**.

I know that MySql provide an **ifnull()** function to do something like this, here the reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

but in this exalmpe it is used on single field on a table. How can I do something like this on my query output?

Comment: Try the Case Statement to replace the Null with a 0?

Comment: How is your problem different from the situation in the link?

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the query might return no results at all (which is looking like `NULL` for the front end?) - not that it is returning a `NULL` value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(intervento.IMP_IND_POS_AFF_MIN), 0)
```

This means `IFNULL` can be applied to the value returned by `SUM` in the same way it is applied to a table field.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use IFFNULL():

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(...), 0 ) FROM ...
```

See also: [Return 0 if field is null in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997327/return-0-if-field-is-null-in-mysql)