# Column Increment value in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

i have a table like this:

```
key | counter | arrived |
123 |         |         |
121 |         |         |
313 |         |         |
543 |         |         |
```

and i need to feel the counter column with an incremental value, and arrived with "1", all like this:

```
key | counter | arrived |
723 |    1    |    1    |
421 |    2    |    1    |
313 |    3    |    1    |
543 |    4    |    1    |
```

i have all these key in an array, and my query is like this:

```
$update = DB::table('Selection')
        ->WhereIn('key', array_keys($req['aff']))
        ->update([
             'arrived' => 1
         ]);
```

in my array `array_keys($req['aff'])` i have all the key  that i need to update, i am able to update the `"arrived"` column with "1"

> but i don't know how to fill the counter column with the incremental
>   value.

i tried this too but with no chance:

```
$update = DB::table('Selection')
            ->WhereIn('key', array_keys($req['aff']))
            ->update([
               'arrived' => 1,
               'counter' => DB::raw('counter+1')
            ]);
```

any suggest?
Thank you in advance and merry xmas :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to use mysql `IFNULL` method here because if your value is null then not increment value so if value is **null then set default** value is **zero**

```
\DB::table('Selection')
            ->whereIn('key', array_keys($req['aff']))
            ->update([
               'arrived' => 1,
               'counter' => \DB::raw('IFNULL(counter,0) + 1')
            ]);
```

for more information read this question [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997327/return-0-if-field-is-null-in-mysql)

> note   mysql datatype must be int and also set default value is zero

in sql server used `ISNULL` function used like that

```
\DB::table('Selection')
                ->whereIn('key', array_keys($req['aff']))
                ->update([
                   'arrived' => 1,
                   'counter' => \DB::raw('ISNULL(counter,0) + 1')
                ]);
```

for more information read this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name. Doesn't work :\

Comment: @GiuseppeLiggieri i update my answer used `ISNULL` method here

Comment: Doesn't work, it fill counter column with all "1". It must increment +1 from the previous record.